# How to invoke JavaScript on hover over an element class or id?

Tags: javascript, title

I have 1,000 links on one page. Each link has a title/note/tool-tip. All the titles say the same thing so rather than typing it up on each line is there a way that I can have javscript do this for me?

Example  Before:

```
<div class="links">
<a href="#" title="This is a title">Tooltips</a> 
<a href="#" title="This is a title">Tooltips</a> 
<a href="#" title="This is a title">Tooltips</a> 
<a href="#" title="This is a title">Tooltips</a> 
</div>
```

Example of what I would like:

```
<div class="links">
<a href="#" >Tooltips</a> 
<a href="#" >Tooltips</a> 
<a href="#" >Tooltips</a> 
<a href="#" >Tooltips</a> 
</div>
```

and have java script display a note when mouseover of "div .links a"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a `data-title="This is a title"` attribute to the container `<div>`. Then on hover of the links, look at its container's `data-title` attribute and display that.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the built-in system tooltips? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm new to javascript i'm sorry. I have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/x2Rzz/)***

[image]

```
var set = document.querySelectorAll(".links a");
var tip = document.createElement("div");
tip.className = "hover";
var msg = document.createElement("div");
tip.appendChild(msg);
msg.innerHTML = "Generic Hover Message";
for( var i = 0, n = set.length; i < n; i++ ){
 set[i].onmouseover = function(){
     this.parentNode.insertBefore(tip,this);
 };
 set[i].onmouseout = function(){
     tip.parentNode.removeChild(tip);
 };
}
```

**Set up events for the target elements**

Use a combination of **[document.querySelectorAll<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)** and iterate through the set assigning the **[onmouseover event<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onmouseover)** and **[onmousout event<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseout)** to each element.

```
var set = document.querySelectorAll(".links a");
for( var i = 0, n = set.length; i < n; i++ ){
 set[i].onmouseover = function(){
```

**Create an element using *[document.createElement<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)* for the tooltip**

```
var tip = document.createElement("div");
tip.className = "hover";
var msg = document.createElement("div");
tip.appendChild(msg);
msg.innerHTML = "Generic Hover Message";
```

**Create styling to position the tooltip**

```
.hover{
 position: absolute;
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
}
.hover > div{
 top: 1.2em;
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

**Use *[insertBefore<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)* to place the element**

```
this.parentNode.insertBefore(tip,this);
```

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? This is literally how you would do it with vanilla js.

Comment: Actually this answer did exactly what I needed it too.. I can't upvote tho due to no rep but i'll accept. Thanks for the answer.. There will always be trolls tho unfortunately.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would hazard a guess that it is because it is something people would usually just post as a comment as it's a one-liner with no code.

Comment: @popnoodles - There is no code, so code is not warranted. Keep in mind that requesting code is specifically off topic on stack overflow.

Comment: Edited a simple example in with more documentation links.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
<div class="links" title="This is a title">
    <a href="#" >Tooltips</a> 
    ...
```

Comment: If all of the links share a common parent element, and the OP is okay with the system styled tool tips, this is a nice solution. No JS required.

Comment: To improve this answer, I would add some explanation about how elements will inherit the title of their parent element.

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.title?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FElement.title#Behavior

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Travis' proposed solution with a querySelector and onmouseover.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Link over</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <style>
         .links{
         }
      </style>
      <script>
         // I show a tooltip
         function showTip() {
            console.log("I'm a tooltip");
         }

         // I set up the listeners
         window.onload = function() {
            var links = document.querySelector("div.links");
            for (var i = 0; i < links.children.length; i++) {
               links.children[i].onmouseover = showTip;
            }
         };
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="links">
         <a href="#">Tooltips</a> 
         <a href="#">Tooltips</a> 
         <a href="#">Tooltips</a> 
         <a href="#">Tooltips</a> 
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```